# Excel VBA - Flipping Numerical Sign

Tags: excel, vba

I have some code that copies data from one tab and pastes it into another tab then flips the numerical sign on an entire column.  Example, -1 in original tab turns to 1 while 1 in original tab turns to -1.

For some reason, if the number in the original tab is a negative, it will not turn positive.  If the number in the original tab is a positive, it will turn negative just fine.  Any ideas of what might be causing this?

The last 3 lines of code is what ultimately flips the signs but I pasted my entire sub in case there's something elsewhere causing the issue.  Thank you in advance!

```
Sub prep()

Dim c As Range
Dim IRow As Long, lastrow As Long
Dim rSource As Range
Dim wsI As Worksheet, wsO As Worksheet
Dim d As Range
Dim dSource As Range
Dim LR As Long



On Error GoTo Whoa


Set wsI = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Ben")

Set wsO = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Upload")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False


wsO.Range("P14", "AB10000").ClearContents

endrow = wsO.Cells(Rows.Count, "T").End(xlUp).Row + 1

With wsI

    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then


        lastrow = .Columns("O:R").Find(What:="*", _
                      After:=.Range("O1"), _
                      Lookat:=xlPart, _
                      LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                      SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                      SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                      MatchCase:=False).Row
    Else
        lastrow = 1
    End If


    Set rSource = .Range("R1:R" & lastrow)



    For Each c In rSource


        Debug.Print c.Value


        If IsNumeric(c.Value) Then
            If c.Value > 0 Then
                wsO.Cells(14 + IRow, 20).Resize(1, 4).Value = _
                     .Range("O" & c.Row & ":R" & c.Row).Value

                wsO.Cells(14 + IRow, 25).Value = "XXXXXX" & .Range("J" & c.Row).Value

                wsO.Cells(14 + IRow, 28).Value = .Range("N" & c.Row).Value

                wsO.Cells(14 + IRow, 16).Value = "470"

                wsO.Cells(14 + IRow, 17).Value = "I"

                wsO.Cells(14 + IRow, 18).Value = "80"

                wsO.Cells(14 + IRow, 19).Value = "A"

                IRow = IRow + 1
            End If
        End If


    Next

End With


For Each r In Range("W14", Range("W" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
            r.Value = -r.Value
Next r
```

Comment: Try r.value*-1. Any difference?

Comment: Do you have the same problem if instead of r.Value = -r.Value, you have r.Value = r.Value * -1?

Comment: @CallumDA gave that a shot just now - does not work.  it'll work with any number that is positive in the original file but none of the ones that are negative in the original file

Comment: @thursdaysgeek yes I do have the same issue.  it will give me the same results where if the number in the original file is positive, it'll work as intended.  if the number in the original file is negative, it will stay negative still

Comment: @thursdaysgeek I just figured it out - I have the line "If c.Value > 0 then ..." which is why the negatives aren't being pulled in.  Do you know how I can change this to be "if c.Value has any numerical value at all then..."?

Comment: Try the IsNumeric() function

Comment: @CallumDA That works!  Thank you!!!!